# Error getting web.py to render html page that calls a css file

Tags: python, html, css, web.py

Ok so I have the web.py file called `app.py`.
`app.py` references `index.html` and `foo.html`.

Both of these html files call just fine, what I mean is when I run `app.py` and go to `http://localhost:8080/` and `http://localhost:8080/Foo` both of them display a webpage just fine, the issue is with the foo.html file tho. I have a large section in there that is supposed to use the `rotate.css` file and make the text in the section spin. The problem is the text doesn't even show up.

Files are below:

`app.py`

```
import web

urls = (
    '/', 'Index',
    '/Foo', 'Foo'
)

app = web.application(urls, globals())

render = web.template.render('templates/')

class Index(object):
    def GET(self):
        greeting_Index = "Hello World"
        return render.index(greeting = greeting_Index)

class Foo(object):
    def GET(self):
        greeting_Foo = 'FooBAR'
        return render.foo(greeting = greeting_Foo)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

`foo.html`

```
$def with (greeting)
$var cssfiles: static/rotate.css

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Foobar</title>
    </head>

<body>
$if greeting:
    <em style="color: red; font-size: 5em;">Welcome to the Foo bar. $greeting.</em>
$else:
    Herro world!

    <section class="rw-wrapper">
        <h2 class="rw-sentence">
            <span>Real poetry is like</span>
            <span>creating</span>
            <div class="rw-words rw-words-1">
                <span>breathtaking moments</span>
                <span>lovely sounds</span>
                <span>incredible magic</span>
                <span>unseen experiences</span>
                <span>happy feelings</span>
                <span>beautiful butterflies</span>
            </div>
            <br />
            <span>with a silent touch of</span>
            <div class="rw-words rw-words-2">
                <span>sugar</span>
                <span>spice</span>
                <span>colors</span>
                <span>happiness</span>
                <span>wonder</span>
                <span>happiness</span>
            </div>
        </h2>
    </section>

</body>

</html>
```

`rotate.css`

```
.rw-wrapper{
    width: 80%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 110px auto 0 auto;
    font-family: 'Bree Serif';
    padding: 10px;
}

.rw-sentence{
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}

.rw-sentence span{
    color: #444;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 200%;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.rw-words{
    display: inline;
    text-indent: 10px;
}

.rw-words span{
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    color: #6b969d;
}

.rw-words-1 span{
    animation: rotateWordsFirst 18s linear infinite 0s;
}

.rw-words-2 span{
    animation: rotateWordsSecond 18s linear infinite 0s;
}

.rw-words span:nth-child(2){
    animation-delay: 3s;
    color: #6b889d;
}

.rw-words span:nth-child(3){
    animation-delay: 6s;
    color: #6b739d;
}

.rw-words span:nth-child(4){
    animation-delay: 9s;
    color: #7a6b9d;
}

.rw-words span:nth-child(5){
    animation-delay: 12s;
    color: #8d6b9d;
}

.rw-words span:nth-child(6){
    animation-delay: 15s;
    color: #9b6b9d;
}

@keyframes rotateWordsFirst {
    0% { opacity: 1; animation-timing-function: ease-in; height: 0px; }
    8% { opacity: 1; height: 60px; }
    19% { opacity: 1; height: 60px; }
    25% { opacity: 0; height: 60px; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes rotateWordsSecond {
    0% { opacity: 1; animation-timing-function: ease-in; width: 0px; }
    10% { opacity: 0.3; width: 0px; }
    20% { opacity: 1; width: 100%; }
    27% { opacity: 0; width: 100%; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

Comment: it looks like you dont have a route that specifies the css file, so when the client requests that css file the server doesnt know what todo, if your using a modern browser check the network tab in the develop console and see if your getting a `404` or `200`

Comment: I am getting a `200`, is that bad, my apologies I am fairly unfamiliar with html. Also, i was under the impression that the `$var cssfiles: static/rotate.css` in the `foo.html` file is what pointed to the css file

Comment: I havent touched web.py since Arron died, but i belive that if you have the files in the static folder they are automatically served, and a `200` means the request is `OK` and a `404` means `Not Found` theyre called `HTTP Response codes`

Comment: so you are thinking that I am missing some type of reference in the `app.py` file about the `rotate.css` file?

Comment: yea that would be my best guess, I created an answer to better explain what i think may be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://webpy.org/cookbook/staticfiles you may have to alter your apache.conf file to allow apache to serve up those files.

And I did notice that nowhere in your html file do you actually link to the css file

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/rotate.css" type="text/css">`

somewhere in the head is missing or since your using it as a variable it should be

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="$cssfiles" type="text/css">`

Comment: i have added `<link rel="stylesheet" href="$cssfiles" type="text/css" />` to the `foo.html` file and it seems that now I am getting an internal server error, think the web.py server is having trouble calling the css file, still working